# Replace ActiveMQ with Kafka in Fineract-CN

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic

Has anyone in Fineract-CN replaced ActiveMQ with Kafka?
I want to use Kafka in Fineract-CN modules, but the Spring Boot version is currently 1.4.1 and is not possible.

Comment: Kafka doesn't depend on Spring, so versions don't matter unless you're trying to use Spring-kafka, which you don't really need for basic functions

Comment: @JustinBertram  I think Kafka do  not implement JMS. So I can not migration from ActiveMQ to Kafka.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have the same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Fineract-CN documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=73634331) says:

> Apache ActiveMQ is used by default, but can be replaced with any Java Messaging Service (JMS) compatible message queue."

However, to my knowledge Kafka does not implement JMS. Therefore, it appears you won't be able to use Fineract-CN with Kafka.